# Need to reload my page to see some elements using Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, materialize

i'm currently working on a University project, and i have to deploy a web page using Rails. 
Using Materialize Css for rails, the only way that, on a form, the element "Select" works is reloading the page, also for others javascripts it seems that they only works reloading the page... Now i'm using a "script" that reloads once the page but its totally a bad practicing

here you have the Application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks

//= require jquery_ujs
//= require materialize-sprockets
//= require_tree .

//= require turbolinks
```

the gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.4'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
#gem 'pg', group: :production
#gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'hirb'
gem 'carrierwave'
#gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.0'
gem 'devise'
gem 'rolify'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'
#gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby
gem 'materialize-sass'
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production  
gem 'puma'
gem 'cloudinary'

#gem 'libv8', '3.11.8.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
```

applications.scss

```
@import "materialize";
```

and finally the _form

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').material_select();
  });</script>
<div class="container">
<%= form_for @articulo, :html =>{:multipart => true} do |f| %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <%= f.text_field :nombre%>
          <label for="first_name">Nombre del producto</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <%= f.text_field :ubicacion%>
          <label for="ubicacion">Ubicación</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="input-field col s6">
          <label for="precio">Precio $</label>
          <%=f.text_field :precio, :class => 'text_field', :min => 0, :step => 0.01, required: true%>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="file-field input-field">
      <div class="btn">
        <span>Imagen</span><input type="file">

       <%= f.file_field :foto %>
      </div>
       <div class="file-path-wrapper">
        <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
        <%= f.text_field :descripcion, :class=> "materialize-textarea"%>
          <label for="textarea1">Descripción</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s6" id="category_id"> 
        <%= f.label :category_id, 'Categoría' %>
          <%= collection_select(:article, :category_id, Category.where(eliminado: false).all , :id, :nombre,class: "browser-default") %>
          </div>
      </div>  
      <br>
          <%= f.submit "Publicar", class: 'btn ' %><%end%>

  </div>
```

------- Edit------
i 've solved this problem; locally it works but when i upload it into Heroku, happens the same... any solution? or how could i update gemfile in heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the problem still occur without turbolinks? I had a similar situation, which I resolved by initially removing this. I realise it's not a full solution, but might point you in the right direction I hope.

There's more info over here: [Rails 4: how to use $(document).ready() with turbo-links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links)

Comment: Great !!! i just comment the Gemfile Where are turbolinks , deleting it of the application.js , and it worked !

Comment: Do you now the reason that it's works locally but not in Heroku?

Comment: Did you 'bundle install' locally and make sure to push the gemfile.lock up when you deployed?

Comment: i think so, i run git add . ;git commit -m "something"; git push heroku master.    How could i checked if i push the gemfile.lock?

Comment: When you run `bundle install` that updates your Gemfile.lock. `git status` will tell you which files are not yet committed.

Comment: Make sure you bundle locally before your git add -A, commit and push heroku. That's the only thing I can think might have stopped it working remotely.